# What are vocabulary relating to "umbrella"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

> **[um‧brel‧la](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/umbrella)** /ʌmˈbrelə/ ●●● S3 noun [countable]      1 Image of umbrellaan object that you use to protect yourself against rain or hot
>   sun. It consists of a circular folding frame covered in cloth →
>   parasol
>
> *It started to rain, so Tricia stopped to put up her umbrella.*
>
> *I spent the day on the beach, lying under a beach umbrella,
>   reading.*

Look at the picture, the woman is pushing the umbrella open or make it open or make it extend. So, how do we say it?

"**She is putting up her umbrella**"?

[But some American speakers say](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/do-you-put-up-or-open-an-umbrella.1775085/) "**to open an umbrella**" is more common

[image]

Now, look at this picture. The umbrella was already opened & she is holding it. What should we say?

"**She is covering herself with her umbrella**" or "**She is hiding herself under her umbrella**"? **Which is more idiomatic?**

[image]

Comment: Where is *hiding?* She's just standing under the umbrella, smiling!

Comment: As a British English speaker I would say 'putting up her umbrella'. I agree with Maulik that the little girl is 'standing under an umbrella'. If it was raining you could say that she was sheltering under it.

Comment: I don't think *hiding* is unnatural as much as literary or expressive. See other **collocations** [here](http://www.freecollocation.com/search?word=umbrella) or [here](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/umbrella?q=umbrella) (the same thing, basically), and [here](https://www.wordreference.com/EnglishCollocations/umbrella).